# python dataframe sum function returning negative number

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a test dataset of the Lending Club loan data and am trying to create some analysis with the set.

After loading the csv into a dataframe, I am just trying to do a simple sum on the entire funded_amnt column.  I keep receiving a negative amount for the sum even though there are no negative numbers in the entire set.  How can this be?

```
In[ ]: loans_df['funded_amnt'].sum()

Out[ ]: -1925852142

In[ ]: len(loans_df[loans_df['funded_amnt']<0])

Out[ ]: 0
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an overflow problem. But it's hard to tell without a [mcve]...

Example:

```
pd.DataFrame([2**61]*2).sum()
Out[345]: 
0    4611686018427387904
dtype: int64

pd.DataFrame([2**61]*3).sum()
Out[346]: 
0    6917529027641081856
dtype: int64

pd.DataFrame([2**61]*4).sum()
Out[347]: 
0   -9223372036854775808
dtype: int64

pd.DataFrame([2**61]*5).sum()
Out[348]: 
0   -6917529027641081856
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Julien.  You put me on the right path.  I wasn't aware that int64 type had an overflow problem in the pydata stack.  Once converting it to a float, it gave me the correct answer.

`loans_df['funded_amnt'].astype('float').sum()`

Comment: by definition `int64` is stored on 64bits so it just cannot go further than `2**64`(in practice it's more like `+/- 2**63`). The python integer type that is unbounded is long `L` for example `2**70 >>> 1180591620717411303424L` but `numpy` and thus `pandas` cannot handle them. To mitigate overflow problems you could use `float` but at the risk of loosing precision...